# Foundation Navigation to slide from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, navbar

I am working with tis navigation >> http://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/foundation-5-top-bar.html

I want it when the hamburger menu shows and you click on it behave slides from Left to right instead of Up to down how it is currently and make the width of the menu that shows up half the way

see screenshot basically when you click on it, the background dim and then it comes from the left (NOT OFF CANVAS)[image]

can anyone help me

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is already included in foundation and it called "off-canvas". Below is the documentations links and an example of what you need to do if you are using Zurb 6.

Zurb 5 - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/offcanvas.html

Zurb 6 - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html

Off canvas menu and website content.

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
      <!-- Your menu or Off-canvas content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
      <!-- Your page content lives here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Off canvas menu trigger.

```
<button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvasLeft">Open Menu</button>
```

Optional close button trigger for use inside offcanvas menu.

```
<button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```